# Google Jobs. Issue when clicking on the preview in Google Job Rich result test

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, googlebot, google-jobs

Recently I have submitted a sitemap with about 30K URLs in it for jobs. Followed the documentation google is providing and now I can see that the sitemap is successfully submitted and in google search console Coverage page I can see about 5K urls which are valid but have type Indexed, not submitted in sitemap, although they exist in the sitemap. Also when I'm testing the url in Rich result test I can see it as eligible for rich result but on clicking the preview it shows page not found.[image]

Any idea on what else I need to do or how I can troubleshoot the issues?

Comment: A similar issue being discussed in google official support https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/48244943/why-im-getting-can-t-find-this-page-the-job-that-you-are-looking-for-may-have-expired-in-search-resu?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that didn't help much, my markup data corresponds to the data I have in the page.